# .firstElementChild, .lastElementChild... what about those in between?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update an existing markup element in React rather than replacing an entire fragment. When I assign a div container element to a variable with .getElement(); I can select the first element within the div with firstElementChild. Then I can find its ".style.color" for example.

Now there's a popover that's the before-last element that I also want to get to it (and its backgroundColor). Not the lastElementChild, the one before that. How do I "get to it"?  Is there an array of children I can use?

Comment: If you look at [MDN: Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) you will see that there are more properties than `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` there is also  [Node.previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling). I don't know react that well but I would guess that there it is also not recommended to directly manipulate the DOM elements created controlled by the component.

Answer (score 1):

> Not the lastElementChild, the one before that. How do I "get to it"?

You can go from the `lastElementChild` to its [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)

> Is there an array of children I can use?

There is a live HTMLCollection  (which is array-like) called [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)

Answer (score 0):

[DOM_Selector_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNUNG.png)

As can be shown in the attached image. Which presents a basic website with the "HTML Tree Generator" Add on.

typing the following in the chrome console:-

```
document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling;
```

Will give you the following results:

```
<p>​ The DOM ​</p>​
```

This is because

```
firstElementChild
```

This is the HTML document

```
lastElementChild
```

This is the Body

```
lastElementChild
```

This is the SCRIPT

```
previousElementSibling
```

This is the element before the SCRIPT which is the text "The DOM"